# Split list into two sublist which has the similar element

Tags: python

I have the list called main_list it as some elements in that I need to divided into to sublist which has pft ('MM19 Z A VDD VNW 'pft' vr\n') and nft ('MM8 Z A VSS VPW 'nft' cpp=8\n')

```
main_list = ['MM19 Z A VDD VNW pft vr\n', 'MM18 Z A VDD VNW pft va\n', 'MM17 Z A VDD VNW pft vdd\n', 'MM16 Z A VDD VNW pft ver\n', 'MM15 Z A VDD VNW pft ger\n', 'MM14 Z A VDD VNW pft fer\n', 'MM13 Z A VDD VNW pft weq\n', 'MM12 Z A VDD VNW pft get\n', 'MM11 Z A VDD VNW pft bet\n', 'MM10 Z A VDD VNW pft wet \n', 'MM9 Z A VSS VPW nft ent=0\n', 'MM8 Z A VSS VPW nft cpp=8\n', 'MM7 Z A VSS VPW nft fpitch\n', 'MM6 Z A VSS VPW nft ngcon\n', 'MM4 Z A VSS VPW nft nfin=4\n', 'MM3 Z A VSS VPW nft cpp=8\n', 'MM2 Z A VSS VPW nft ent=0\n', 'MM1 Z A VSS VPW nft l=1.4e-08\n', 'MM0 Z A VSS VPW nft cpp=8\n']
```

Result:

```
pft_list = ['MM19 Z A VDD VNW pft vr\n', 'MM18 Z A VDD VNW pft va\n', 'MM17 Z A VDD VNW pft vdd\n', 'MM16 Z A VDD VNW pft ver\n', 'MM15 Z A VDD VNW pft ger\n', 'MM14 Z A VDD VNW pft fer\n', 'MM13 Z A VDD VNW pft weq\n', 'MM12 Z A VDD VNW pft get\n', 'MM11 Z A VDD VNW pft bet\n', 'MM10 Z A VDD VNW pft wet \n']
nft_list = ['MM9 Z A VSS VPW nft ent=0\n', 'MM8 Z A VSS VPW nft cpp=8\n', 'MM7 Z A VSS VPW nft fpitch\n', 'MM6 Z A VSS VPW nft ngcon\n', 'MM4 Z A VSS VPW nft nfin=4\n', 'MM3 Z A VSS VPW nft cpp=8\n', 'MM2 Z A VSS VPW nft ent=0\n', 'MM1 Z A VSS VPW nft l=1.4e-08\n', 'MM0 Z A VSS VPW nft cpp=8\n']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list iteration :

```
pft_list = [i for i in main_list if 'pft' in i]
nft_list = [i for i in main_list if 'nft' in i]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your `main_list` and sort the entries into the sublists by checking if `pft` or `nft` is `in` the entry:

```py
pft_list = []
nft_list = []
for x in main_list:
    if 'pft' in x:
        pft_list.append(x)
    elif 'nft' in x:
        nft_list.append(x)
```

Comment: It's strange, because I copied your lists and my code works and results the desired outputs. Can you check `main_list`?

Comment: you're welcome. Do not forget to vote and accept answers :)

Comment: Please add some commentary on what the code does that solves the problem